# how to handle pywinauto opened edge default browser to selenium and work on dom elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge, pywinauto

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pywinauto import application, timings

app = application.Application()
app.start("C:/Program Files (x86)/.../msedge.exe")
main_window = app.top_window()
main_window.set_focus()
handle = main_window.handle #output - some Integer 
handle_hex = hex(handle)[2:]
driver = webdriver.Edge("path for edge driver")
driver.switch_to.window(handle_hex) # error - no such window, tried with both handle and handle hex

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is only capable of detecting a window that is created within the **same WebDriver session**, so it is expected that it throws "no such window". You can also learn that from the difference between 2 types of handles:

For **pywinauto**: handle = 6096004

handle_hex = 5d0484

For **Selenium**: 6EAD1EE6C4DC207ADD67479339FF7A72